# Visual Studio Code: Remote-SSH connect to Windows Server 2019

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I've set up my VSCode Insider to connect th a Windows 2019 Server via the Remote-SSH extension. Is it correct, that I need a WSL installed so that it can set up the VSCode-Server and then it is running within the WSL distro when I'm connected?

I thought it would run on Windows instead.

Answer (score 0):

The stable VS Code 1.40 release does not support for Windows ssh hosts: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_remote-ssh-limitations

This feature is still experimental and only enabled in [VS Code insiders builds](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) **when you set `"remote.SSH.remoteIsWindows": true`** (Make sure to use the [nightly ssh extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly) too) See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/25#issuecomment-536791856) for details

Comment: Is there a progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to run WSL. You need to install a ssh client on your local machine (the machine that you will run VS Code), and install a ssh server on your remote machine. That's all you need. Your local VS Code uses the ssh client to connect to that ssh server on the remote machine. Details of how to do this can be [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse), including opening firewall ports in the case of Windows.