# How to connect from a Mac's VSCode to a Windows Server 2012 VM via SSH?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the [Remote SSH VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) to connect to a Windows 2012 Server from my mac.

However, everytime, it fails

What I can do

- The extension works for my Linux VMs.
- I can ssh via the terminal to the Windows 2012 server with `ssh Administrator@vmipaddress`

What I've tried

- I've installed an OpenSSH server by following this tutorial to no avail.
  (https://www.kjctech.net/setting-up-sftp-or-ssh-server-on-windows-server-2012-r2/z)
- I installed the Insiders edition and the nightly ssh extension to follow this answer [Visual Studio Code: Remote-SSH connect to Windows Server 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802685/visual-studio-code-remote-ssh-connect-to-windows-server-2019)

I'm running Catalina on my Mac.

Comment: Have you checked the SSH version used on the Mac vs. on the Linux VM?  Also, RedHat Linux can have multiple versions installed, but only one version will be the "active" version.  Could be a difference between OpenSSH 1.1.x vs. 1.0.x or similar? It may also be that your SSH key file on the Mac is in the wrong format for use by a Mac?  (PEM vs. DER in a key file.)

Comment: Sorry I've updated the question to clarify that I'm trying to connect from my Mac to a Windows 2012 server.